# How to prevent a PHP file called in action form to appear as a page?

Tags: php, forms, action

With this line

```
form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="manageMySQLGuests.php" method="post"
```

I cannot avoid manageMySQLGuests.php to appear as a page whilst only  CRUD transactions with MySQL occur in this PHP file (so that nothing needs to appear as I manage failures in another way).

Comment: Is AJAX what you want?

Comment: I suppose not having to use ajax in order to prevent a blank page to appear on the same tab (nor to a new one) in order to execute background MySQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the same action inside the same script where resides the form when the form with its variable is submitted, or after processing inside "manageMySQLGuests.php" redirect back to the original script by command

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Many thanks. header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); It seems to work but I have to test more.

Answer (score 0):

I used already JavaScript functions to validate form’s input fields at the presentation layer. Nothing prevents me to validate and make calculations in the business layer, and even if necessary, at the data layer with triggers. I have only a HTML / Javascript presentation layer and a PHP Data layer to interact with MySQL. At this stage, it is enough because I am discovering too many technologies at the same time in web developing (that is not my brilliance) to afford managing the complication induced by an intermediate business layer (at this stage at least). So, I replace all CRUD actions triggered by buttons (in a section outside the form) without submitting the form by ajax function working only in background and avoid in this way form’s refresh which are not desirable and disrupt all the mechanism. In others words, I have replaced the implicit POST from the post method of the form by ajax $.post for all fields of this form in functions defined for each CRUD action, and it works perfectly, transparently.
Thanks to Ajax, I made a giant step which will be engraved in gilt lettering in the mythology of Stackoverflow